# Smoothing in sculpt mode but not by Smooth tool

Tags: sculpting, sculpt

Can anybody tell me how the guy from the video is smoothing out the nose in his sculpture?
https://youtu.be/TLb_CCoWn5o?t=261
I know that he is using one of those: Draw, Clay, Clay Strips or Layer, but I'm trying to achieve this I think 4th hour and failing. I have similar poly to smooth, but Smooth tool destroys my object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I guess the answer is in your question  ;)   it looks like if you use the *Clay* brush with a high *Autosmooth* you add geometry without deforming the general shape. Also, maybe he sometimes switches to the *Smooth* brush with the <kbd>shift</kbd> shortcut. Of course make sure that your *Dyntopo* is activated with a low enough *Detail Size* (the lower it will be the smaller the geometry will be) and the *Subdivide Collapse* and *Relative Detail* options activated (so that the detail size will depend on your zooming).

Comment: Oh man, thank you! Autosmooth - that was it! :D